# CORS preflight request is redirected and didn't passed

Tags: cors, preflight

On my website, when user session is expired, the website redirects user to login page, nevertheless I have this CORS issue which doesn't allow me to do this:

`...response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

Because it redirects and return the code of 302 instead of 2xx

Are there any workarounds?